# Random access (quasi-?)random sequence

Tags: random-number-generation, random-sampling

Fix a dimension $d \ge 1$.  Is there an efficiently computable sequence $f : \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]^d$ such that

1. $f$ is either random or quasirandom (e.g., similar to Sobol sequences).
2. Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a box $S = [a_0,b_0] \times \cdots \times [a_{d-1},b_{d-1}]$, one can find the subset $f_{S,n} = \{f_k | k<n, f_k \in S\}$ in output sensitive time $O(\operatorname{poly}(\log n +|f_{S,n}|))$.

The motivation is that such a sequence would provide a nice way to use non-jittery, low-noise sampling when zooming around in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a paper by Gruenschloss about enumerating Sobol points falling within some elementary intervals: https://github.com/lgruen/sample-enum

This is used in [pbrt](https://pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Sampling_and_Reconstruction/Sampling_Interface#GlobalSampler) with the global sampler in order to figure out which samples correspond to which pixel, namely the part about getIndexForSample. You can find it for Sobol here: https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/blob/master/src/samplers/sobol.cpp and the SobolIntervalToIndex can be found here: https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/blob/master/src/core/lowdiscrepancy.h